# Deserializing json array using gson

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

Continuing from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414021/how-do-i-modify-a-large-json-string).

I'm having trouble deserializing the following json array (Sorry for the size):

```
"geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 771230.894373, 4422896.962001 ],
 [ 804804.852796, 4451159.130080 ], [ 876828.563339, 4417873.954498 ], [ 959794.979827, 
4430944.287708 ], [ 910992.515063, 4372980.866944 ], [ 932488.308736, 4357684.778349 ], 
[ 918573.372386, 4115663.286966 ], [ 834059.614976, 4013708.358795 ], [ 929360.231044, 
3833522.241529 ], [ 1008029.715188, 3776446.653183 ], [ 1061663.445852, 3533717.758754      
], [ 1035703.740599, 3519308.069656 ], [ 1095348.723766, 3396028.487184 ], [ 
1108462.159782, 3230455.268230 ], [ 1083571.121640, 3163122.508021 ], [ 1103953.720405, 
3082716.041755 ], [ 1045722.494771, 3020215.642212 ], [ 1117367.719045, 2915275.458735 
], [ 1141268.013718, 2827405.304519 ], [ 1286729.192338, 2790314.754276 ], [ 
1334329.406601, 2695307.513404 ], [ 829417.592210, 2374337.277646 ], [ 647042.870444, 
2207530.090128 ], [ 370914.873531, 2152159.656850 ], [ 346669.488436, 2173360.227237 ], 
[ 359905.375891, 2251757.174668 ], [ 199905.871774, 2309591.361246 ], [ 129963.835709, 
2361036.252651 ], [ 130208.738589, 2404106.913263 ], [ -964785.432600, 3159802.671416 
], [ -964829.960396, 3338713.127631 ], [ -851005.781060, 3424742.002477 ], [ -
616522.405653, 3491025.523892 ], [ -547749.224241, 3569019.334331 ], [ -403724.067052, 
3628920.873754 ], [ -423973.082428, 3724062.779415 ], [ -333893.350478, 3741450.793542 
], [ -317696.364567, 3774909.265404 ], [ -131414.328674, 3777826.527844 ], [ -
112467.751341, 3830221.719769 ], [ -185682.580436, 3930014.456814 ], [ -194499.084106, 
4129581.855629 ], [ -245950.952751, 4175549.526399 ], [ -42303.076294, 4287174.981681 
], [ -11222.674464, 4271148.905617 ], [ 131633.628071, 4371332.547494 ], [ 
433220.392528, 4427574.250017 ], [ 593119.709103, 4389089.571176 ], [ 719645.442339, 
4451856.882422 ], [ 771230.894373, 4422896.962001 ] ] ] }
```

If I paste it into a json-viewer, I get this structure:

```
[geometry]
...
[coordinates] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 771230.894373
                        [1] => 4422896.962001
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 804804.852796
                        [1] => 4451159.13008
                    )
                ...
                [n] => Array
        [n] => Array
```

Now, the array containing the arrays with the coordinates has a variable size. So I figured that in java, this whole object whould be an array, containing a collection of arrays, with each array containing a `Collection<double[]>`. Something like `Collection<double[]>[][].`

But gson does not accept this. I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Expecting object but     
found array: 2.963610
```

Which seems weird, as `2.963610` doesnt look like an array to me. But it might have confused me to the point where I'm lost, more or less...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think I know where your problem comes from, reading the Gson API :

> If the object that your are
>   serializing/deserializing is a
>   ParameterizedType  (i.e. contains at
>   least one type parameter and may be an
>   array) then you must use the
>   toJson(Object, Type) or
>   fromJson(String, Type) method. Here is
>   an example for serializing and
>   deserialing a ParameterizedType:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<LinkedList>() {}.getType();
List target = new LinkedList();
target.add("blah");

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(target, listType);
List target2 = gson.fromJson(json, listType);
```

Knowing that

```
Type typeOfCollectionOfFoo = new TypeToken<Collection<Foo>>(){}.getType()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This might be a part of my problem. I've tried this:
Type coordinates = new TypeToken<Collection<Collection<Collection<Collection<Double>>>>>(){}.getType();

But this just gives me an error-msg saying that it failed to deserialize [jsonstring].

Comment: Just stumbled upon this old question - accepted your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

The `coordinates` in JSON is a three-dimensional matrix. With `Collection<double[]>[][]` you're going one dimension too far. The `Collection` itself is already one dimension, so you've basically declared a four-dimensional matrix.

With the error message, Gson is basically telling you that it is expecting an object for the fourth dimension, but it instead encountered a double.

The following represent valid three-dimensional matrices which should be perfectly handled by Gson:

- `private double[][][] coordinates;` (recommended)
- `private Collection<double[]>[] coordinates;`
- `private Collection<double[][]> coordinates;`
- `private Collection<Collection<double[]>> coordinates;`
- `private Collection<Collection<Collection<Double>>> coordinates;`

---

That said, I would prefer [`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) above [`Collection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) in this particular case. With a `List` you can guarantee that it's been filled with insertion order and you'll be able to [get](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) elements by index.

Comment: This seems about right, except that the number of outer arrays in the [coordinates] array isnt fixed. In my example, there is only 1. (It goes [coordinates] => Array( [0] => Array ( [0] => array ... ) ), 
but it could also contain, say 2 arrays:

[coordinates] => Array ( [0] => Array ( ... )  [1] => Array ( ... ) )

Hope this makes sense? So I guess we need another collection somewhere (or list)?

Comment: If I just add another dimension, like private Collection<Collection<Collection<Collection<Double>>>> coordinates; I get this exception:

Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonParseException: The JsonDeserializer com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter@929206 failed to deserialized json object 2.963610 given the type com.google.gson.ParameterizedTypeImpl@b6a924

Comment: Then create a wrapper object representing the coordinates which can hold children in a collection and implement a custom deserializer by extending `JsonDeserializer`.

Answer (score 2):

According to Gson user guide:

**Serializing and Deserializing Generic Types**
When you call toJson(obj), Gson calls `obj.getClass()` to get information about the fields to serialize. Similarly, you can typically pass `MyClass.class` object in the `fromJson(json, MyClass.class)` method. This works fine as long as the object is a non-generic type. However, if the object is of a generic type, then the generic type information is lost because of [Java Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Here is an example illustrating the point:

```
List<String> myStrings = new List<String>();
gson.toJson(myStrings); // Will cause a runtime exception

gson.fromJson(json, myStrings.getClass());
```

The above call results in a runtime exception because Gson invokes `myStrings.getClass()` to get its class information, but this method returns a raw class, `List.class`. This means that Gson has no way of knowing that this is a list of Strings, and not plain objects.

You can solve this problem by specifying the correct parameterized type for your generic type. You can do this by using the `TypeToken` class.

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
gson.toJson(myStrings, listType);

gson.fromJson(json, listType);
```

The idiom used to get `listType` actually defines an anonymous local inner class containing a method `getType()` that returns the fully parameterized type.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think we'd need more details, such as what you wrote for the deserialization.

Comment: I simply wrote this:

Data data = new Gson().fromJson(json.toString(),Data.class);

The Data object is a simple java-object with getters and setters for the fields, sharing the name of the json attributes. Coordinates is one of these attributes, found in a Geometry class.