# Parsing a nested json string using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

```
[{"body":"{\"id\":\"act_105099966308460\",\"account_id\":105099966308460,\"name\":\"\",\"account_status\":2,\"currency\":\"USD\",\"timezone_id\":1,\"timezone_name\":\"America\\\/Los_Angeles\",\"timezone_offset_hours_utc\":-7,\"is_personal\":0,\"business_name\":\"\",\"business_street\":\"44916
Winding
Lane\",\"business_street2\":\"\",\"business_city\":\"Fremont\",\"business_state\":\"CA\",\"business_zip\":\"94539\",\"business_country_code\":\"US\",\"vat_status\":0,\"daily_spend_limit\":25000,\"users\":[{\"uid\":100004253709632,\"permissions\":[1,2,3,4,5,7],\"role\":1001}],\"notification_settings\":{\"100004253709632\":{\"1000\":{\"1\":1},\"1001\":{\"1\":1},\"1002\":{\"1\":1,\"2\":60},\"1003\":{\"1\":1,\"2\":60},\"1004\":{\"1\":1},\"1005\":{\"1\":1},\"1006\":{\"1\":1},\"1009\":{\"1\":1},\"1010\":{\"1\":1},\"1011\":{\"1\":1},\"2000\":{\"1\":1,\"2\":60},\"2001\":{\"1\":1,\"2\":60},\"2002\":{\"2\":60},\"2003\":{\"1\":1,\"2\":60},\"2004\":{\"1\":1,\"2\":60},\"2005\":{\"1\":1,\"2\":60},\"3000\":{\"1\":1,\"2\":60},\"3001\":{\"1\":1,\"2\":60},\"3002\":{\"2\":60},\"3003\":{\"2\":60},\"5000\":{\"1\":1},\"6000\":{\"1\":1},\"6001\":{\"1\":1},\"9000\":{\"1\":1,\"2\":60},\"8000\":{\"1\":1,\"2\":60}}},\"account_groups\":[{\"account_group_id\":344615332296926,\"name\":\"my
test
group\",\"status\":1},{\"account_group_id\":218621204934411,\"name\":\"inmobi
Ads
group\",\"status\":1},{\"account_group_id\":267052626739836,\"name\":\"Test
ad account
group1\",\"status\":1}],\"capabilities\":[2],\"balance\":0,\"moo_default_conversion_bid\":1000,\"amount_spent\":0}"}]
```

I want to parse this string as object, but it is failing. Pojo and code I am using :

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<BatchAccounts>>(){}.getType();

Gson gson = new Gson();

List<BatchAccounts> results = gson.fromJson(response1, listType);

public class BatchAccounts
{
    private Account body;

    public Account getBody()
    {
        return body;
    }

}


public class Account
{

    private String id;

    private String account_id;

    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public String getAccount_id()
    {
        return account_id;
    }

}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Expecting object found: "{\"id\":\"act_105099966308460\",\"account_id\":105099966308460,\"name\":\"\",\"account_status\":2,\"currency\":\"USD\",\"timezone_id\":1,\"timezone_name\":\"America\\/Los_Angeles\",\"timezone_offset_hours_utc\":-7,\"is_personal\":0,\"business_name\":\"\",\"business_street\":\"44916 Winding Lane\",\"business_street2\":\"\",\"business_city\":\"Fremont\",\"business_state\":\"CA\",\"business_zip\":\"94539\",\"business_country_code\":\"US\",\"vat_status\":0,\"daily_spend_limit\":25000,\"users\":[{\"uid\":100004253709632,\"permissions\":[1,2,3,4,5,7],\"role\":1001}],\"notification_settings\":{\"100004253709632\":{\"1000\":{\"1\":1},\"1001\":{\"1\":1},\"1002\":{\"1\":1,\"2\":60},\"1003\":{\"1\":1,\"2\":60},\"1004\":{\"1\":1},\"1005\":{\"1\":1},\"1006\":{\"1\":1},\"1009\":{\"1\":1},\"1010\":{\"1\":1},\"1011\":{\"1\":1},\"2000\":{\"1\":1,\"2\":60},\"2001\":{\"1\":1,\"2\":60},\"2002\":{\"2\":60},\"2003\":{\"1\":1,\"2\":60},\"2004\":{\"1\":1,\"2\":60},\"2005\":{\"1\":1,\"2\":60},\"3000\":{\"1\":1,\"2\":60},\"3001\":{\"1\":1,\"2\":60},\"3002\":{\"2\":60},\"3003\":{\"2\":60},\"5000\":{\"1\":1},\"6000\":{\"1\":1},\"6001\":{\"1\":1},\"9000\":{\"1\":1,\"2\":60},\"8000\":{\"1\":1,\"2\":60}}},\"account_groups\":[{\"account_group_id\":344615332296926,\"name\":\"my test group\",\"status\":1},{\"account_group_id\":218621204934411,\"name\":\"inmobi Ads group\",\"status\":1},{\"account_group_id\":267052626739836,\"name\":\"Test ad account group1\",\"status\":1}],\"capabilities\":[2],\"balance\":0,\"moo_default_conversion_bid\":1000,\"amount_spent\":0}"
    at com.google.gson.JsonObjectDeserializationVisitor.visitFieldUsingCustomHandler(JsonObjectDeserializationVisitor.java:100)
    at com.google.gson.ReflectingFieldNavigator.visitFieldsReflectively(ReflectingFieldNavigator.java:63)
    at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:120)
```

Comment: Are all those quotes *supposed* to be escaped ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458930/deserializing-json-array-using-gson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a JSON string nested inside the other JSON object, you need two parsing steps to parse this structure, something like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

List<BodyHolder> bodies = gson.fromJson(response1, 
   new TypeToken<List<BodyHolder>>() {}.getType());

List<BatchAccounts> result = new ArrayList<BatchAccounts>(bodies.size());
for (BodyHolder holder: bodies) {
    BatchAccounts a = new BatchAccounts();
    a.setBody(gson.fromJson(holder.getBody(), Account.class);
    result.add(a);
}

public class BodyHolder
{
    private String body;
    ...    
}
```

Also you can implement the second step as a custom [`JsonDeserializer`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html).