# Converting JSON into java parse

Tags: java, json

I'm performing a query on my server which returns tree information in JSON format. Below

```
[{"leaf": 0, "context": {}, "text": "ABC-1-6-1", "expandable": 1, "id": "1.1.2.202.ABC-1-6-1", "allowChildren": 1}]
```

I was having play round with json-simple library and can parse it ok using JSONParser if can get the above info in String format i.e.

```
String jsonString = "{\"leaf\": 0, \"context\": {}, \"text\": \"1.1.2.202.ABC-1-6-1\", \"expandable\": 1, \"id\": \"1.1.2.202.ABC-1-6-1\", \"allowChildren\": 1}";
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: What the question is ?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: I want to parse the JSON data into java

Comment: @daverocks This is a json  array will you give me the full string including name?

Comment: means you want to convert json to java object?

Comment: @Parvathy yes, so I need to do a JSONArray to java

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/   http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/  and more others...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert JSON to java then use gson. it is very simple.

```
  Person fromJson = new Gson().fromJson(json, Person.class);// this will convert json to java object
        fromJson.setAge(15);
        fromJson.setName("json");
        fromJson.setEmail("email@gmail.com");
        fromJson.setMob("4657576876");

        json = new Gson().toJson(fromJson);// this will convert java to json string like this {"name":"json","age":15,"email":"email@gmail.com","mob":"4657576876"}
```

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Refer the following link for json array convertion

[serialize and deserialize json array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458930/deserializing-json-array-using-gson)

Answer (score 0):

You have many [JSON parsers for Java](http://www.json.org/java/)