# Java object with variable-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, json, generics, gson

I'm trying to parse a [GeoJSON](http://www.geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) using [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), and I have an JSON that looks something like this (simplified):

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "name": "Afghanistan", "geometry": 
    { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": 
        <<a 3-dimensional double array (double[][][] in Java)>>
    } 
},
{ "type": "Feature", "name": "Indonesia", "geometry":
    { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates":
        <<a 4-dimensional double array (double[][][][] in Java)>>
    }
},
//etc...
 ]
}
```

I need to have a java class that can be correlated with the Gson object in order to use it, but I'm struggling on what to with an array of similar objects whose variable `coordinates` is not the same. I have the equivalent of:

```
class FeatureCollection{
    String type;
    Feature[] features;
}
class Feature{
    String type,name;
    Shape geometry;
}
class Shape{
    String type;
    ??? coordinates;
}
```

- When I try to use `double[][][]` instead of `???`, I get a `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a double but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 6 column 146`
- When I try making `Shape` an abstract class and use subclasses for `MultiPolygon` and `Polygon`, `Gson` tries to instantiate a `Shape` and errors.

Can I use generics or something else sneaky to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to have your own custom [JsonDeserializer](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html) since the `coordinates` variable doesn't have a set of defined array dimensions. I recommend using an interface for the shape, then writing a deserializer for it, like so:

```
public interface Shape {

    ShapeType getType();

    enum ShapeType { Polygon, MultiPolygon }
}
```

Then implementations for each type. `ShapeType.Polygon`:

```
public class PolygonShape implements Shape {

    private final ShapeType type = ShapeType.Polygon;
    private double[][][] coordinates;

    public ShapeType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public double[][][] getCoordinates() {
        return coordinates;
    }

    public void setCoordinates(double[][][] coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }
}
```

And `ShapeType.MultiPolygon`:

```
public class MultiPolygonShape implements Shape {

    private final ShapeType type = ShapeType.MultiPolygon;
    private double[][][][] coordinates;

    public ShapeType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public double[][][][] getCoordinates() {
        return coordinates;
    }

    public void setCoordinates(double[][][][] coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }
}
```

Then lastly, your deserializer will rely on the `type` from each implementation:

```
public class ShapeDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Shape> {

    @Override
    public Shape deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        ShapeType type = context.deserialize(jsonObject.get("type"), ShapeType.class);
        switch (type) {
            case Polygon:
                return context.deserialize(json, PolygonShape.class);
            case MultiPolygon:
                return context.deserialize(json, MultiPolygonShape.class);
            default:
                throw new JsonParseException("Unrecognized shape type: " + type);
        }
    }
}
```

Using this, you can also create other implementations based on the type of shape and add them to the `switch` to support them. For example, to support a new `Line` type:

```
case Line:
    return context.deserialize(json, LineShape.class);
```

Don't forget to register it with the [`GsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#registerTypeAdapter%28java.lang.reflect.Type,%20java.lang.Object%29) method:

```
GsonBuilder builder;
// ...
builder.registerTypeAdapter(Shape.class, new ShapeDeserializer());
```